# FireMonkey - get access to the buttons of a TScrollBar

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to get access to the `Max` & `Min` buttons of a `TScrollBar`. Looking at the code at `FMX.StdCtrls.pas` file, turns out that those buttons are protected. The parent of the `TScrollBar` is a `TStyledControl`, wich do not publish those properties, threfore I can't find a way to get accesss to those buttons by hacking the `TScrollBar` parent as we used to do in the `VCL`framework. I wonder if there is a workarround to do this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: By *Max & Min buttons*, do you mean the thumbs? What are you trying to do specifically? This sounds like an XY problem where you're trying to thing X to get Y to work, when you may not need Y in the first place. What specifically are you trying to do which makes you think you need to access those buttons? What would you do with them  if you *could* access them?

Comment: @ Ken. Yes, the thumbs. My goal is to be able to paint them according to mouse events, with colors other than standard colors. I know that it can be done with styles, but i've unsuccesfully tried that way. Besides I think (at least for me) that working with styles is a very tricky task (not to mention that documentation on the subject is very poor). I've also posted a question about styling a `tListBox` but got no answer yet. I appreciate if you can help me with this issue.